# Woocommerce wc_create_order() not working

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, webhooks

I'm creating a website which handles payment from stripe using wp simple pay plugin.

I created a webhook that will allow me to know if the payment is successful or not. If it is success, I will create an order that has data in it but postman always returning 500 Internal Server Error and I cannot see the error from it.

If I remove the `wc_create_order()` and return the $address, it worked perfectly. I am suspecting that I've doing something wrong in my code.

Here's the code I'd created

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'pinion_add_order');
function pinion_add_order($m, $a) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $address = array(
        'first_name' => 'Project Paid ',
        'last_name'  => $m
    );

    $order = wc_create_order();
    $order->add_product(($a == '100000' ? get_product('2858') : get_product('2859')), 1);
    $order->set_address($address, 'billing');
    $order->set_address($address, 'shipping');
    // $order->set_total($amount);
    $order->calculate_totals();
    $order->update_status("Completed", 'Imported order', TRUE);  

    return $order;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You should not use wp simple pay plugin with woocommerce that way in `WC_Checkout` hooks… This will never works in a clean way. You should better use Woocommerce Stripe plugin or search about create an order programmatically in stackOverFlow (as this has been already answered a lot)... `WC_Checkout` methods and hooks habe to be used With Woocommerce integrated payment methods or/and gateways…

Answer (score 2):

Although *LoicTheAztek* is correct and there is probably a better way of doing this, the answer to your question is that you haven't saved the Order object.

So before your return statement, try adding `$order->save();`

This will actually save the values to the database.

If that doesn't work, you may also need to adding some additional properties, such as a payment method using `$order->set_payment_method($string);`

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I hope the below code help you.

```
function pinion_add_order() {
    global $current_user;
    $a = '100000';
    $order          =   wc_create_order();
    $order->add_product(($a == '100000' ? get_product('2858') : get_product('2859')), 1);
    //$order->add_product( $_product, $item_quantity );
    $order->calculate_totals();

    $fname          =    get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'first_name', true );
    $lname          =    get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'last_name', true );
    $email          =    $current_user->user_email;
    $address_1      =    get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'billing_address_1', true );
    $address_2      =    get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'billing_address_2', true );
    $city           =    get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'billing_city', true );
    $postcode       =    get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'billing_postcode', true );
    $country        =    get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'billing_country', true );
    $state          =    get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'billing_state', true );

    $billing_address    =   array(
        'first_name' => $fname,
        'last_name'  => $lname,
        'email'      => $email,
        'address_1'  => $address_1,
        'address_2'  => $address_2,
        'city'       => $city,
        'state'      => $state,
        'postcode'   => $postcode,
        'country'    => $country,
    );
    $address = array(
        'first_name' => $fname,
        'last_name'  => $lname,
        'email'      => $email,
        'address_1'  => $address_1,
        'address_2'  => $address_2,
        'city'       => $city,
        'state'      => $state,
        'postcode'   => $postcode,
        'country'    => $country,
    );

    $shipping_cost = 5;
    $shipping_method = 'Fedex';

    $order->add_shipping($shipping_cost);

    $order->set_address($billing_address,'billing');

    $order->set_address($address,'shipping');

    $order->set_payment_method('check');//

    $order->shipping_method_title = $shipping_method;

    $order->calculate_totals();

    $order->update_status('on-hold');

    $order->save();
}
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'pinion_add_order'); //it does not take any parameters.
```

For more help please see the file and class structure in file : `\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\class-wc-checkout.php`

Comment: shipping has it's own handler ```WC_Order_Item_Shipping()```